# How to get the differences for two REST API responses?

Tags: java, json, rest, json-patch

I would like to compare two rest api responses in Java.
Currently I am using zjsonpatch library and with that I am able to get the difference but the difference contains the value of one of the jsons. I would like to have both the json nodes.

Please find below my code:

```
    ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode beforeNode = jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(jsonActual);
    JsonNode afterNode = jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(jsonCurrent);
    JsonPatch patch = JsonDiff.asJsonPatch(beforeNode, afterNode);
    String diffs = patch.toString();
```

Below is the output I am getting

```
op: replace; path: "/businessServiceabilityResponse/0/serviceabilityDetail/0/serviceabilitySource"; value: "ELOC"]
```

Is there a way I can get both the nodes which are not matching?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two JsonNodes with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871675/how-to-compare-two-jsonnodes-with-jackson)

Comment: No. This is doing only assertion and returning a boolean.

Comment: What exactly do you want in the output? Node at `/businessServiceabilityResponse/0/serviceabilityDetail/0`?

Comment: @Smile I want the nodes of both the files which are different like /businessServiceabilityResponse/0/serviceabilityDetail/0/serviceabilitySource"; value: "ELOC"] and /businessServiceabilityResponse/0/serviceabilityDetail/0/serviceabilitySource"; value: "ELOC1"]... This will clearly show the difference

Comment: I don't know if any libarary can do this out of box. But you can write some custom logic to find the mismatching values from both json file based on the path returned by zjsonpatch

Comment: @Smile could you please elaborate more on what you are suggesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert)

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(json1, json2, true);
```

json1:

```
[
  {
    studentname: "John",
    john: "123"
  },
  {
    studentname: "Ram",
    Ram: "124"
  }
]
```

json2

```
[
  {
    studentname: "Nhoj",
    john: "123"
  },
  {
    studentname: "Ram",
    Ram: "124"
  }
]
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: [0].studentname
Expected: john
     got: Nhoj

    at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:417)
    at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:394)
    at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:336)
    at com.smilep.java.thirteen.so.JSONAssertExample.main(JSONAssertExample.java:32)
```

Comment: It does not solve my purpose. I need the differences.